# I don't know really well how to declare a string, (former pawn programmer learning C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, implicit-conversion, assignment-operator, string-literals

years ago i was a programmer in a C++ derivated language that was called Pawn, now i want to try to start in C++, write some things to unrust myself from this beatiful thing that is programming

No, i have never coded with C++ before and with any other language that was not Pawn.

This is the first time i use stackoverflow, sorry if i'm asking a stupid question.

So, this is my code:

I tried to do what the code says like its done in Pawn, almost, and well, i have errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> // I don't know if this is needed
#include <string> // The same for this
using namespace std; // I don't know what this means


int main()
{  
    int number;   

    printf("Write the number of croisssants you eat a day\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("The number of croissants that you eat a day is %d", number);

    char finalMessage[64]; // This is the way it was made in Pawn, you declare a string and put a max for text

    switch(number)
    {
        // So here i try to use a switch to do this, like i was used to, yes i know how to use if but i'm trying to see if it's this metod is the same thing as it is in Pawn.
        case 0: finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
        case 1: finalMessage = "Thats okay";
        case 2: finalMessage = "Well, if one, why not two?";
        default: finalMessage = "Mmmm, i think they are too much.";
    }

    printf("%s", finalMessage);

    return 0; 
}
```

The errors are all this:

error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [11]' to 'char [64]'
20 |         case 1: finalMessage = "Thats okay";

You can imagine the other ones being the same.

I tried reading a lot of "How to declare a string in C++ but because 2 things...

1. I don't understand advanced programming terms (i.e. initialization, constant, cout, etc), i'm working in that
2. English is not my first language (It's Spanish), yes, maybe i should use the Spanish forum but i'm trying to get used to the English one because i'm supposed to work with this one in the future

... i can't resolve this.

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only copy to it (with e.g. `strcpy` for strings). *Or* you could make `finalMessage` a pointer (`char const* finalMessage;`), which you can assign to.

Comment: With that said, whatever resource you're using to learn C++, it seems to teach you C, not C++. Please invest in [some decent C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn "proper" C++.

Comment: Your code looks like you are trying to write C, not C++. All the C++-specific parts are not relevant. Learn C++ from structured material, e.g. one of the [recommended books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Looks more like C to me. If you really want to use C++, you should make `finalMessage` a `std::string` instead of a char array, i.e. `std::string finalmessage;`. Then you only need to replace the `printf`calls by `std::cout`s.

Comment: `using namespace std; // I don't know what this means`  [Let me help you understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: One of your mistakes is to try associate two languages by their similarity. First, Pawn never was based on C++, it used C-syntax though and similarity in functions are due to similar environment, not due to language similarity.  C++ is very different from Pawn and C.

Answer (score 1):

Since you had quite a few questions packed into your code, I've made some changes and commented on them:

```cpp
//#include <cstdio>    // this is the correct C++ header, I won't use it though

#include <iostream>  // I don't know if this is needed
// it's needed if you are using the C++ i/o streams, like std::cin and std::cout

#include <string>  // The same for this
// it's needed to be able to use std::string, which you are not, but you should

// using namespace std; // I don't know what this means
//  it means that you can skip writing std:: infront of all
//  classes/functions/constants that are placed in the std namespace
//  Don't use it for now. It's often causing problems until you know when to use it.

int main() {
    int number;

    //puts("Write the number of croisssants you eat a day");
    std::cout << "Write the number of croisssants you eat a day\n";

    /* The C way:
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid number, bye bye\n");
        return 1;
    }
    */
    if(!(std::cin >> number)) { // the C++ way:
        std::cerr << "invalid number, bye bye\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // printf("The number of croissants that you eat a day is %d", number);
    // Using std::cout instead:
    std::cout << "The number of croissants that you eat a day is " << number << '\n';

    // char finalMessage[64];
    std::string finalMessage; // use a std::string instead

    switch (number) {
        case 0:
            finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
            break; // needed, or else it'll continue to the next case
        case 1:
            finalMessage = "Thats okay";
            break; // needed, or else it'll continue to the next case
        case 2:
            finalMessage = "Well, if one, why not two?";
            break; // needed, or else it'll continue to the next case
        default:
            finalMessage = "Mmmm, i think they are too much.";
    }

    //printf("%s\n", finalMessage.c_str());  // or
    //puts(finalMessage.c_str());            // or the c++ way:
    std::cout << finalMessage << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator.

So such an assignment like this

```
finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
```

is invalid.

In these statements

```
    case 0: finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
    case 1: finalMessage = "Thats okay";
    case 2: finalMessage = "Well, if one, why not two?";
    default: finalMessage = "Mmmm, i think they are too much.";
```

you are using string literals that have static storage duration. To make the code correct just declare the variable `finalMessage` as having the type `const char *`:

```
const char *finalMessage;
```

In this case in assignments like this

```
finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
```

the string literal is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and this pointer will be assigned to the pointer `finalMessage`.
There is no need to use objects of the type `std::string` in your simple program.

Also you need to use the statement break to pass the control after each labeled statement outside the switch statement

```
switch(number)
{
    // So here i try to use a switch to do this, like i was used to, yes i know how to use if but i'm trying to see if it's this metod is the same thing as it is in Pawn.
    case 0: finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
            break;
    case 1: finalMessage = "Thats okay";
            break;
    case 2: finalMessage = "Well, if one, why not two?";
            break;
    default: finalMessage = "Mmmm, i think they are too much.";
            break;
}
```

As for the comment in this line

```
using namespace std; // I don't know what this means
```

then in your program it is redundant because neither name from the namespace `std` is used in your program.

Standard C++ names as for example `cout` or `string` are declared in the namespace `std`. Without the using directive you need to use qualified names as for example

```
std::string s( "Hello" );
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Including the using directive you may write

```
using namespace std;
//...

string s( "Hello" );
cout << s << '\n';
```

Also pay attention to that names of headers from C you should prefix with the letter 'c' that is instead for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

you should write

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using mostly C concepts rather than C++.

In C++, we would use `string` instead of an array of chars. Additionally, we would use `cin` (C in) and `cout` (C out) for input and output. Try the following:

```
#include <iostream> // This is needed for cin/cout
#include <string> // This is needed to use string
using namespace std; // Basically this means you can write cin instead of std::cin, string instead of std::string, etc.


int main()
{  
    int number;   

    cout << "Write the number of croisssants you eat a day\n"; //cout instead of printf
    cin >> number; //cin instead of scanf. Note that you don't need to specify types
    cout << "The number of croissants that you eat a day is " << number;

    string finalMessage; // In C++, we use strings instead of char arrays

    switch(number)
    {
        // Switches should work the same way
        case 0: finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants"; break;
        case 1: finalMessage = "Thats okay"; break;
        case 2: finalMessage = "Well, if one, why not two?"; break;
        default: finalMessage = "Mmmm, i think they are too much.";
    }

    cout << finalMessage;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` isn't needed. And you're missing `break` statements in the `switch`.

Comment: I would urge [against recommending `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).  Stack Overflow gets countless questions about mysterious bugs caused by the inclusion of that detested line.

Comment: @DrewDormann I definitely never use namespace std personally, but as a beginner it may make more sense to see `string` rather than `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are trying to get into C++ I would recommend ditching the pure char arrays and the C style IO (`printf` and `scanf`). Instead replace them with  the more modern `std::string` and IO (`std::cout` and `std::cin`).

Rewriting this in modern C++ would look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    int number;   

    cout << "Write the number of croisssants you eat a day" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "The number of croissants that you eat a day is " << number << endl;

    string finalMessage;

    switch(number)
    {
        case 0: 
            finalMessage = "Oh, so you don't like croissants";
            break;
        case 1: 
            finalMessage = "Thats okay";
            break;
        case 2: 
            finalMessage = "Well, if one, why not two?";
            break;
        default: 
            finalMessage = "Mmmm, i think they are too much.";
    }

    cout << finalMessage << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am not familiar with pawn but in C++ in switch statements you have to use `break` before the next case if you don't want fallthrough.

Also `using namespace std;` just specifies that you are going to use the standard namespace by default. Allows you to type `cout << "Something";` instead of `std::cout << "Something"`. However it is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)